# EF Error When Use Linq With Stored Procedure

Tags: linq

Attempts were as follows:

```
var query1 = Db.ProductView.Where(w => w.DisplayFlag == "Y");
var paging = query1.Include(i => i.ProductImages).Select(s =>

                        new Products()
                        {
                            ProductCode = s.ProductCode,
                            DesignCode = s.DesignCode,
                            Code1 = s.Code1,
                            Code2 = s.Code2,
                            ProductImages = s.ProductImages.Where(i => (i.ImageNo == 1 & i.ImageType == "LS") ).Select(i => i), 
                            ProductCoupons = Db.Database.SqlQuery<Coupon>("EXEC [USP_Front_EShop_Coupon_Select_By_ProductCode] @ProductCode", s.ProductCode)

                        }
                );
```

However, the following error was returned:

> *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable `1
>   [Lesmore1.Models.Coupon SqlQuery [Coupon] (System.String,
>   System.Object [])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>   Help us understand what is going wrong ..

Answer (score 1):

`SqlQuery` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, which may be why you are getting that error.

Try putting `.Single()` or `.First()` after the call to `SqlQuery` to get a single object, or `.Select()` or `Where()` to get a sequence of objects.

Comment: Hmm... The error is returned because a part of your LINQ to SQL can't be translated to T-SQL. Perhaps `Coupon` is not defined in the LINQ model?

Comment: Thank You...of course coupon Model exists..Can't code with StoredProcedure in Linq??